# Android Google Cloud messaging issue in server registeration?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I have trying to run GCM sample application but I'm facing fatal exception in my logcat(my applications forced to close) It's indicate server URL link is invalid URL. if I run my URL link its showing "No device registered". if invalid URL means it's show error right but it's shows "No device registered". so I'm confused. why I'm facing this problem.

logCat :

```
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid url: 192.168.1.2:8080/home/register
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ServerUtilities.post(ServerUtilities.java:138)
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.ServerUtilities.register(ServerUtilities.java:66)
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.DemoActivity$2.doInBackground(DemoActivity.java:88)
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.DemoActivity$2.doInBackground(DemoActivity.java:1)
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
03-04 16:28:11.691: E/AndroidRuntime(770):  ... 5 more
```

Code :
http://paste.org/62112

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's cause of "invalid url: 192.168.1.2:8080/home/register"... 
It seems you didn't uploaded code to webserver yet. You'll have to upload Server code Live server.

Answer (score 1):

Take in Mind that here the Method `ServerUtilities.register(..)` is static and will take RegId as Argument and Register this Id to server. you will have to do your code in this method same as like we are posting any String to our Server with GET or POST Method :

your Method will looks like as Below after Doing code :

```
static boolean register(final Context context, final String regId) {

        String URL = CommonUtilities.SERVER_URL+"&device=" + regId;

        Log.v("URL : ", URL);
        JSONObject json = fetchTwitterPublicTimeline(URL);

        try {
            Log.i("Json : ", json.toString());
            String login_msg = json.getString("MESSAGE");
            Log.i("Reply : ", login_msg);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your device is not registered yet,because of the server url given is wrong.check and give a valid url .